# Use factor theorem to find all zeros of polynomial $2x^3+3x^2+x+6$ with one known factor $x+2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

I am to find the factors of  $2x^3+3x^2+x+6$ where I am told that$x+2$ one of the factors.
Using synthetic division to divide $2x^3+3x^2+x+6$ by $x+2$ I confirm there is no remainder so it is a zero and the new quotient is $2x^2-x+3$

So I have: $(x+2)(2x^2-x+3)$

I would now like to factor $(2x^2-x+3)$ but am having a hard time. Since my leading coefficient is not 1, I know that in order to factor by grouping I must find two numbers whose sum is -1 and whose product is 6 (leading coefficient 2 * constant term 3).

I cannot find any so do not know how to proceed with factoring $(2x^2-x+3)$.

I considered:
-1 & 6: product = -6, sum 5
1 & -6: product = -6, sum -5
2 & -3: product = -6, sum -1 # close
-2 & 3: product = -6, sum 1  # also close
-2 & -3: product = 6, sum 5

How can I factor $(2x^2-x+3)$?

Comment: Do you know about the connection between the roots of a polynomial and its factorisation?

Comment: Hint: if a quadratic factors over the reals, then it has a real root. Does $x^2 - x + 3$ have a real root?

Comment: Not all quadratics factor into linear factors. In this case, $2x^2-x+3$ is *irreducible*, and can't be factored further using real numbers.

Comment: @DougFir As others have *commented* and *answered* the original cubic equation has one real root and (as pointed out in Gio's analysis of a discriminant) two complex roots.  The problem that you originally stated : "I am to find the factors of ..." is **ambiguous**.  Is the assignment to prove that there are no other real roots?  If so, you can use the analysis in Gio's answer.  Alternatively, is the assignment to **also** explicitly identify the two complex roots?  If so, (again) the analysis in Gio's answer is a good starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$2x^2-x+3=2(x^2-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{3}{2})$ where the discriminant is $\Delta=(\frac{-1}{2})^2-4\times 1\times \frac{3}{2}=\frac{1}{4}-6<0$. Therefore $x^2-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{3}{2}$ has no real roots and so it is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$.